# Integral problem, evaluating the substitution at zero...

Tags: integration

So I have to show the following:

$$\int_0^v \frac{x^a}{(x+k)^{2a+2}} dx = \int^{\infty}_{k^2/v} \frac{u^a}{(u+k)^{2a+2}}du$$

By making a suitable substitution. Where $k>0$ and $a$ is a positive integer. Clearly we have to divide by $x$ to obtain the infinity. So my substitution was $u = \frac{k^2}{v-x}$. I reasoned that $x \rightarrow v^-$ $\implies$ $u \rightarrow + \infty$. But if one proceeds with such substitution it is very hard to show that the integral on the LHS is the same as the one on RHS (at least I was not able to show it). The solution, however, uses the substitution: $u = \frac{k^2}{x}$, and I wonder what gives them right to use this substitution. We cannot divide by zero, but we can consider what happens to this substitution when $x$ approaches zero.But in our case, the lower bound is $0$, so it is definite. I am confused...

Comment: Actually, your substitution is valid and virtually the same with the solution's. Why not read the solution and do it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the integral as $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_\epsilon^\nu\frac{x^a}{(x+k)^{2a+2}}\ dx$$ Substitute $u=\frac{k^2}{x}$. After multiplying top and bottom by $u^{2a+2}$ and dividing top and bottom by $k^{2a+2}$ we get $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{k^2/\nu}^{1/\epsilon}\frac{u^a}{(u+k)^{2a+2}}\ du=\int_{k^2/\nu}^{\infty}\frac{u^a}{(u+k)^{2a+2}}\ du$$

Comment: Once more, a downvote for a good answer ! $+1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici To be fair the downvote came in a split second before I deleted the answer and about 1 sec after I had put it up. At that point I had not read the question beyond the first line or two, had not noticed the OP already had the substitution $u=\frac{k^2}{x}$, and had failed to deal with his worries about $1/0$!

Comment: Your comments reveals a nice behaviour and attitude. Congratulations and thanks for being such. I really appreciate your comment. Cheers.

Comment: Ok i see. Thanks!